# How to Seed value to aspnet_UsersInRoles in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, aspnetdb

I'm currently creating an application with EntityFramework and aspnet membership tables combined.

To create the aspnet membership tables dynamically, I followed this tutorial: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/563/using-entity-framework-code-first-and-aspnet-membership-together

My problem is the `aspnet_UsersInRoles` table. To map the table I modified `OnModelCreating` and add the ff code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AspnetUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.AspnetRoles)
                .WithMany(r => r.AspnetUsers)
                .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.ToTable("aspnet_UsersInRoles");
                        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                        m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                    });
```

It created successfully the `aspnet_UsersInRoles` table, but my problem is that I don't have a class/entity for this and I'm unable to initialize value when I override the `Seed` method.

Creating an entity `aspnet_UsersInRoles` also doesn't work because the many-to-many relationship between `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_Roles` create a new table.

Any idea on how to do this? Having many to many relationship between `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_Roles` using the table `aspnet_UsersInRoles` and initializing values in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Role`s to `AspnetRoles` collection property of the `AspnetUser` class.

```
var role = new AspnetRole { Name = "Foo" };
var user = new AspnetUser { Name = "Bar", /*other props*/ };

user.AspnetRoles = new List { role };

context.Users.Add(user);
```

This will add "Foo" role to the "Bar" user.